# C# foreach loop - is order *stability* guaranteed?

Tags: c#, collections, foreach

Suppose I have a given collection. Without ever changing the collection in any way, I loop through its contents twice with a foreach. Barring cosmic rays and what not, is it absolutely guaranteed that the order will be consistent in both loops?

Alternatively, given a `HashSet<string>` with a number of elements, what can cause the output from the the commented lines in the following to be unequal:

```
{
    var mySet = new HashSet<string>();
    // Some code which populates the HashSet<string>

    // Output1
    printContents(mySet);

    // Output2
    printContents(mySet);
}

public void printContents(HashSet<string> set) {
    foreach(var element in set) {
         Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

It would be helpful if I could get a general answer explaining what causes an implementation to not meet the criteria described above. Specifically, though, I am interested in `Dictionary`, `List` and arrays.

Comment: What kind of collection?

Comment: I am most interested in Dictionary, but it would be nice to have an overview of all of them.

Comment: Given that there's only so many implementations of .NET, I think you might have better luck just looking at their source codes/decompilations. It's not like C++ where there's a gazillion implementations and the wrong assumptions give you undefined behavior...

Comment: Dictionary for sure you can't assume with enumerate in the same order. That's what a Sorted Dictionary is for.

Comment: Good question.  Now please excuse me while I create a class called `RandomList` where the enumerator randomly iterates the elements.  Mwuhaha!

Comment: @scottheckel but it is reasonable to expect that enumeration will be stable until the dictionary is modified. This makes a lot of things easier to do when consuming the collections as read-only without requiring the (likely inconsequential) overhead that a sorted dictionary has.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Array enumeration guarantees order.

`List` and `List<T>` are expected to provide stable order (since they are expected to implement sequentially-indexed elements).

Dictionary, HashSet are explicitly do not guarantee order. Its is very unlikely that 2 calls to iterate items one after each other will return items in different order, but there is no guarantees or expectations. One should not expect any particular order.

Sorted versions of Dictionary/HashSet return items in sort order.

Other IEnumerable objects are free to do whatever they want. Normally one implements iterators in such a way that it matches user's expectations. I.e. enumeration of something that have implicit order should be stable, if explicit order provided - expected to be stable. Query to database that does not specify order should be expected to return items in semi-random order.

Check this question for links: [Does the foreach loop in C# guarantee an order of evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097769/does-the-foreach-loop-in-c-sharp-guarantee-an-order-of-evaluation?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

Everything that implements `IEnumerable<T>` does so in its own way.  There is no general guarantee that any given collection must ensure stability.

If you are referring specifically to `Collection<T>` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) I don't see any specific guarantee in its MSDN reference that ordering is consistent.

Will it probably be consistent?  Yes.  Is there a written guarantee? Not that I can find.

Comment: Excellent! Not to mention that the order of a set doesn't matter, so a HashSet would by definition still be correct in not always returning things in the same order.  A SortedSet would though for sure.

Comment: @Hexxagonal: A HashSet would be correct in not *guaranteeing* a stable order of iteration.  As a practical matter you probably will get the same order if you iterate the same HashSet twice without changing it's internal state between iterations.  It's unlikely that the first iteration will do anything to change internal state.  Then again, it might.  Thus no *guarantee* :-)

Comment: How **wouldn’t** `Collection<T>.GetEnumerator()` return things in a stable order? It defines [`Collection<T>.Item(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132434.aspx) which means that you can do `for (var i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++) { var x = collection[i]; }` and be guaranteed to see all elements. That can’t happen without also resulting in a stable enumeration order, can it? Or, at the very least, you could write your own enumerator that uses `Item(int)` since that *has* to be stable to be usable.

Comment: @binki: As a matter of actual implementation, you're right. There's no guarantee that `Collection<T>` in fact works that way, but current implementations (and probably future implementations) do.

Answer (score 3):

For many of the C# collections there are **sorted** versions of the collection.  For instance, a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) is to a [`SortedSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) as a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) is to a [`SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx).  If you're working with something where the order isn't important like the `Dictionary` then you can't assume the loop order will behave the same way every time.

Answer (score 0):

As per your example with `HashSet<T>`, we now have source code to check: [HashSet:Enumerator](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,61c6bd9b8ecf54e9)

As it is, the `Slot[] set.m_slots` array is iterated.
The array object is only changed in the methods `TrimExcess`, `Initialize` (both of which are only called in the constructor), `OnDeserialization`, and `SetCapacity` (only called by `AddIfNotPresent` and `AddOrGetLocation`).

The values of `m_slots` are only changed in methods that change elements of the `HashSet`(`Clear`, `Remove`, `AddIfNotPresent`, `IntersectWith`, `SymmetricExceptWith`).

So yes, if nothing touches the set, it enumerates in the same order.

[Dictionary:Enumerator](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,73212bdb7b191713) works in quite the same way, iterating an `Entry[] entries` that only changes when such non-readonly methods are called.